# Ошибка с pyqiwip2p, ошибка декодировки, в чем проблема?

Tags: python

```
auth_qiwi='BLABLABLA'
p2p=QiwiP2P(auth_key=auth_qiwi)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gelse\PycharmProjects\telebot_wildber\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    p2p=QiwiP2P(auth_key=auth_qiwi)
  File "C:\Users\gelse\PycharmProjects\telebot_wildber\venv\lib\site-packages\pyqiwip2p\Qiwip2p.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.validate_privkey(auth_key)
  File "C:\Users\gelse\PycharmProjects\telebot_wildber\venv\lib\site-packages\pyqiwip2p\Qiwip2p.py", line 94, in validate_privkey
    key_decoded = b64decode(privkey).decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-5: invalid continuation byte

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Ругается на строку с создание p2p клиента.

Comment: А всю ошибку, что там выводит, можно? Про private_key

Comment: @Виктор поправил вопрос.

Comment: validate_privkey - вероятно надо валидный ключ, в base64 кодировке

Comment: @Виктор а как это можно сделать?

Comment: Видимо надо получить ключ на Qiwi (может у них есть тестовый сервер) и подставить его в auth_key=....  Читайте у них на сайте

Comment: @Виктор спасибо, я неправильно получал ключ, нужна пара ключей.